# How retrive specific data from XML file using ajax?

Tags: javascript, xml

I want to fetch the specific data from an xml file using ajax.

```
function loadXMLDoc(url)
{
page = 1;
perPage = 3;
content = document.getElementById('bookList');
pagination = document.getElementById('pageUL');
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET",url,false);
    xmlhttp.send();
    xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML; 
    records = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("book");
    paganation(1);
 }
```

this function is call onload event.
this above function work properly.
My Xml File:

```
<CATALOG>
<book category="A"><book_title>aaaa</book_title><book_desc>aa</book_desc></book>
<book category="B"><book_title>aaaa</book_title><book_desc>aa</book_desc></book>
<book category="A"><book_title>aaaa</book_title><book_desc>aa</book_desc></book>
</CATALOG>
```

but problem is that how to get specific data like category is "A" or "B"

Comment: What is `paganation`? The name is confusing btw as it looks like a typo.

Comment: What do you do with `records`, where do you access the single books from which you need a category?

Comment: @Bergi Sorry My mistake is a pagination & it is function in which i can display data

Comment: Nope, `pagination` is the `#pageUL` element not a function. To fix such minor mistakes, feel free to [edit] your question.

Answer (score 0):

Just call the [`getAttribute` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.getAttribute) on a single `<book>` node:

```
/* your loop over records */ {
    var book = records[i];
    var category = book.getAttribute("category");
    // do anything with the data
}
```